# Replacing values in JSON string using JSON.net library (C#)

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got a JSON string. I need to replace some values in it. I do it this way:

```
string jsonString = "{\"id\": \"5281959998_126883980715630\", \"name\": \"The New York Times\", \"category\": \"Company\"}";
JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
jObj["category"] = "inc";
string strJson = jObj.ToString();
```

But it doesn't work properly! Symbols "\r\n" appears after each key-value pair. What am I doing wrong? How can I prevent appearance of these symbols?

Comment: Given that it's still valid JSON with the same meaning, why do you really care? You can always just replace `"\r\n"` with `""` if you really want to.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Or use the correct method...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `ToString()` you can't change this behaviour. It is [documented](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) that this method returns *indented* JSON.

You need to use [the overload](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) instead:

```
var result = jObj.ToString(Formatting.None);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I completely forgot about it!

Answer (score 1):

In fact with `\r\n`s or not, they are valid jsons.

```
string strJson = jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None, null);
```